# Read ipywidgets slider value in infinite loop

Tags: python, jupyter-lab, ipywidgets

I am trying to read a slider value in an infinite loop, but there is no print output. My goal is to control a robot with sliders, and the robot needs a constant stream of information even if the slider value doesn't change, thus the infinite while loop.

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display

slider = widgets.IntSlider()
display(slider)

while True:
    if slider.value != 0:
        print(slider.value)
```

Comment: You need to look into asynchronous widget use. When your code is in the `while` loop, no updates to widgets get sent. https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Asynchronous.html

Comment: great thanks, i managed to make it work with below library, in this case async didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to make it work using this library: https://pypi.org/project/jupyter-ui-poll/

```
global slider_result_value
with ui_events() as poll:    
    # this unfreezes the ui and allows slider event handlers to fire
    # allowing sliders to update global variables which can be read out
    poll(10) # poll for 10 ui events

    do_something(slider_result_value)
```

Answer (score 1):

This thread has saved me. The `jupyter_ui_poll` library works so well. It is exactly what I wanted.

Here is an example of using `jupyter_ui_poll` together with `asyncio`. It is a simple FM audio receiver app inside a Jupyter Notebook.

```py
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()

import asyncio
from jupyter_ui_poll import ui_events

sdr.center_freq = 92_700_000 # an FM radio station running at 92.7MHz

async def streaming():
    it = 0
    async for data in sdr.stream():        
        # perform FM demodulation
        audio = fm_demodulation(data)

        # poll UI events
        with ui_events() as poll:
            poll(10)
            sdr.center_freq = slider.value

        # play the audio
        display(Audio(audio, autoplay=True, rate=48000, normalize=False))
        
        it = it + 1
        if it == it_num:
            break

slider = widgets.IntSlider()

display(slider)
    
asyncio.run(streaming())
```

I have omitted some implementation in the above code. Just to give an idea.